# How to Find All the Files with the filename format Heena_Report_MMDDYYY.CSV through Unix Command from date March 2016 till date?

Tags: shell

I want to find the files which are kept in my local directory with the  filename format Heena_Report_MMDDYYY.CSV through Unix Command from date March 2016 till date?? Moreover i want to keep the files for the current month in the specific folder and previous all month files i want to delete.. I am writing one automation script where this logic has to be incorporated. Please Help.

Comment: Show us what you have tried...

Comment: Since these filenames have your name in it, it's fairly probably your fault that the date is MMDDYYY, rather than the intelligent order YYYYMMDD which sorts lexicographically in order of increasing date. Don't write dates like that to a computer.